# what is this component ?5A_Z120_25M_0805_2P

Tags: laptop

hi what i should to write on google to find out this component 5A_Z120_25M_0805_2P is in my laptop.
i try to find out on google but no info there is

Comment: Hard to say for sure.  My guess is it's a ferrite bead rated for 5A and has an impedance of 120 ohms in an 0805 package.

Comment: Searching that exact P/N on Google brings up [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503749/help-identifying-inductor-from-a-schematic) as the first result, which answers your question.